# JPA: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file in JavaSE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am making a small program to migrate data from another system we don't own, to a custom one we are making inside our company. I am using IntellJ with Maven, but the error seems to come from the target folder after building as It seems unable to find the folder, and when I browse inside it, Intellij gives me an error.

persistence.xml  in src/ I cut a bit so I don't bloat this post with a big image.
[image: Persistence.xml in src/]

Here is a small screenshot of the output after doing compiling as you can see the files are placed where they belong.

[image: Output after compile]

And when I check the persistence.xml inside the folder, here Intellij says that the files cannot be resolved.

[image: target folder persistence.xml]

This is not the original location of those xml files, as they were generated by the IDE inside the package edu.apde.f5.model.$project, at first they were not included in the build so I moved them inside the resources/META-INF/etc path, and they appeared, but It is still giving the same error. Also tried with the path META-INF/$project-mapping and still nothing.

Error received in output, this is the error I get after trying to run the project, this occurs when I call Entity Manager and I call the "MsSchoolPersistenceUnit"

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : src/main/resources/META-INF/msschool-mapping/ScReligion.xml : origin(src/main/resources/META-INF/msschool-mapping/ScReligion.xml)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:214)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:82)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:99)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:232)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:174)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:76)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:171)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:119)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at edu.apde.f5.util.EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager(EntityManagerUtil.java:12)
at edu.apde.f5.data.msschool.AlumnoRepository.fetchAll(AlumnoRepository.java:17)
at edu.apde.f5.main.Main.main(Main.java:10)
... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: The mapping-file path needs to be relative to the root of the CLASSPATH, or be absolute. Are they????

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel I updated the question with the error.

Comment: Post text not images.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There.

Comment: There what? I still see 3 images.

Answer (score 0):

The Classpath needs to point to the containing folder of src/main/resources/META-INF/msschool-mapping/ScReligion.xml.

Another option is to modify the mapping file entry to point to the file relative to the existing Classpath.

Another option is to give it an absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to point your mapping file to META-INF/msschool-mapping/ScFamiglia.xml
Es.

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/msschool-mapping/yourorms*.xml</mapping-file>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a leading "/" before `src` in every `<mapping-file></mapping-file>` tag.